# keep folder structure of source files in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I have one .html page(index.html) and one entry point(index.js) and I want that dist folder keeps folder structure of my source files.

```
 ./webpack.config.js
 ./src/index/index.html
 ./src/index/index.js
 ./src/index/script1.js
 ./src/index/style1.scss
 ./src/assets/imgs/bg.jpg
```

I manage to write a webpack config file that works as I want but only when I use 'npm run build' and webpack give me a final build version.'
if I use 'npm run dev' then dev server opens a page that shows directories list.
How can I solve my problem?
this is my webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    },
    entry: {'index': './src/index/index.js'},
    output: {
        filename: '[name]/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                            reloadAll: true,
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
                            reloadAll: true,
                        },
                    },
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: false,
                            publicPath: './'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'assets/imgs/',
                            publicPath: '../assets/imgs/'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "[name]/[name].css",
            chunkFilename: '[id].css',
            ignoreOrder: false
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            filename: 'index/index.html',
            inject: true,
            chunks: ['index'],
            template: './src/index/index.html'
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin()
    ]
};
```

package.json :

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  }
```

I want dist folder to be like this :

```
./dist/index/index.html
./dist/index/index.js --> final .js bundle
./dist/index/index.css --> final .css bundle 
./dist/assets/imgs/bg.jpg
```